# A question about the dual map of $A \otimes B \to B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $A$, $B$ be two algebras. Suppose that we have an action $\varphi: A \otimes B \to B$ and there is a pairing $\psi: A \otimes B \to \mathbb{C}$. The action $\varphi$ induces a map $\delta: B 
\to A^* \otimes B$ defined as follows: $\delta(b) = \sum b_{(1)} \otimes b_{(2)}$, $\sum b_{(1)} \otimes b_{(2)}$ is the  notation, $b_{(1)} \in A^*$, $b_{(2)} \in B$, $b_{(1)}(a) b_{(2)} = \varphi(a, b)$, $b_{(1)}(a) = \psi(b_{(1)}^*, a)$. Is the map $\delta$ a homomorphism of algebras? Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you define $b_{(1)}^*$? Do you have a canonical isomorphism $A^*\to A$?

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon, thank you very much. I define $b_{(1)}^*$ as follows: $b_{(1)} \in A^*$, $b_{(1)}^*$ is the element in $A$ which is dual to $b_{(1)}$. I assume that we have a canonical isomorphism $A^{**} \to A$. I think that if we take $A = U_q(g)$ and $A^* = \mathbb{C}_q[G]$, where $g$ is the Lie algebra of a Lie group $G$, then we have a canonical isomorphism $A^{**} \to A$. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see what $b^*_{(1)}$ is. Even with a given isomorphism $A^{**}\to A$, that is not enough to deduce a canonical isomorphism $A^{*}\to A$, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon, thank you very much. I am trying to compute the map $\delta: B \to A^* \otimes B$. For example, when $A = U_q(sl_2)$, $A^*=\mathbb{C}_q[SL_2]$. The algebra $A = U_q(sl_2)$ is generated by $E, F, K, K^{-1}$ subject to certain relations. The algebra $A^*=\mathbb{C}_q[SL_2]$ is generated by $a,b,c,d$ subject to the relation $ad-bc=1$. There is a natral pairing between $A$ and $A^*$:

Comment: \begin{align}
& \phi(E,a)=0, \ \phi(E,b)=1, \ \phi(E,c)=0, \ \phi(E,d)=0, \\
& \phi(F,a)=0, \ \phi(F,b)=0, \ \phi(F,c)=1, \ \phi(F,d)=0, \\
& \phi(K,a)=q, \ \phi(K,b)=0, \ \phi(K,c)=0, \ \phi(K,d)=q^{-1}.
\end{align}
Therefore we can obtain $\delta$ by using this pairing. Is this correct?